# Add file extension to temporary file

Tags: uploads

I am using download_url() to download a temporary file and want to save this file in my uploads folder using media_handle_sideload. This works fine with files that have a file extension.

media_handle_sideload dosent work with files that have no file extension. So when im trying to save for example [this](http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_GZpK4xgnBQbNLlSh8d0YUY7Nznz4Q_Th8UCjOYPVRGNRGC1mGegyyNFOSwC) image it wont save, because the url has no file extension.

Then I need to use `image_type_to_extension(exif_imagetype($imageurl));` to get the file extension for the image. How can I add this file extension to the temporary file?

here is my code:

```
public function upload_image_from_url($imageurl) {

        // Get the file extension for the image
        $fileextension = image_type_to_extension(exif_imagetype($imageurl));

        // Save as a temporary file
        $tmp = download_url( $imageurl );

        $file_array = array(
            'name' => basename( $imageurl ),
            'tmp_name' => $tmp
        );

        // Check for download errors
        if ( is_wp_error( $tmp ) ) {
            @unlink( $file_array[ 'tmp_name' ] );
            return $tmp;
        }

        $id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, 0 );
        // Check for handle sideload errors.
        if ( is_wp_error( $id ) ) {
            @unlink( $file_array['tmp_name'] );
            return $id;
        }

        $attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $id );


        return $attachment_url;

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The problem:

When you download an image with an extension, for example `jsbach_image.jpg`, it will look like this in the temp directory:

```
/tmp/jsbach.tmp
```

but when you download an image without an extension, for example `mozart_image`, you will get:

```
/tmp/mozart
```

But the latter one will not pass the [filetype- and extension tests](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-admin/includes/file.php#L424) in the `wp_handle_sideload()` function, called by the `media_handle_sideload()` function.

### A possible solution:

We can trick it to pass the test, by *renaming* (or *copying*) the temp file with an extension.

You can try the following modifications:

```
/**
 * Upload an image from an url, with support for filenames without an extension
 * 
 * @link   http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/145349/26350
 * @param  string $imageurl
 * @return string $attachment_url
 */
function upload_image_from_url( $imageurl )
{
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

    // Get the file extension for the image
    $fileextension = image_type_to_extension( exif_imagetype( $imageurl ) );

    // Save as a temporary file
    $tmp = download_url( $imageurl );

    // Check for download errors
    if ( is_wp_error( $tmp ) ) 
    {
        @unlink( $file_array[ 'tmp_name' ] );
        return $tmp;
    }

    // Image base name:
    $name = basename( $imageurl );

    // Take care of image files without extension:
    $path = pathinfo( $tmp );
    if( ! isset( $path['extension'] ) ):
        $tmpnew = $tmp . '.tmp';
        if( ! rename( $tmp, $tmpnew ) ):
            return '';
        else:
            $ext  = pathinfo( $imageurl, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
            $name = pathinfo( $imageurl, PATHINFO_FILENAME )  . $fileextension;
            $tmp = $tmpnew;
        endif;
    endif;

    // Upload the image into the WordPress Media Library:
    $file_array = array(
        'name'     => $name,
        'tmp_name' => $tmp
    );
    $id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, 0 );

    // Check for handle sideload errors:
    if ( is_wp_error( $id ) )
    {
        @unlink( $file_array['tmp_name'] );
        return $id;
    }

    // Get the attachment url:
    $attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $id );

    return $attachment_url;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to hear that, I hope you can modify this demo to your needs.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I had to check the extension on $imageurl instead, and if that's not present, do the name change. I was getting .tmp always even with files without extension.

Comment: @AlainJacometForte thanks for your feedback. Did something change in WordPress since this was posted last year, or is this something specific to your install/environment?